# Dynamic Report title base on parameter selection in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi i have a report where i have 2 parameters and each parameter is populated by getting the value from their respective  Data-set. Now i want to create the title of the Report in a way that if the User Select just one account number then i want to display that **Account Number** in the title; But if User select more that ONE account Number from the drop down then i want to display the value Select in the Second parameter which **CUSTOMER NUMBER**. Anyone can Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have solved the query so i am posting my answer if in future anyone has the same question; in the placeholder expression i have to put the following expression: `IIF(PARAMETERS!ACCOUNT.COUNT = 1, PARAMETERS!ACCOUNT.VALUE(0), PARAMETERS!CUSTOMER.VALUE(0))`